# Recursive method for level order traversal

Tags: binary-tree

The `levelOrder` method needs to call itself recursively to perform level order traversal. I'm having trouble in how to add (this) to accumulator. This is what I have so far.

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> left;
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> right;
    private T data;

    public BinaryTreeNode() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode(T theData) {
        this(theData, null, null);
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode(T theData, BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild,
            BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild) {
        data = theData;

        left = leftChild;
        right = rightChild;
    }

    public void levelOrder(
            SortedMap<Integer, List<BinaryTreeNode<T>>> accumulator, int depth) {

        accumulator.put(depth, this);// add (this) to accumulator

        if (left != null) {
            left.levelOrder(accumulator, depth);// if (left) is not null invoke
                                                // this method for left
        }
        if (right != null) {
            right.levelOrder(accumulator, depth);// do the same for (right)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UAB CS 302? Ok here's how I did it:

You have to check to see whether or not the accumulator contains a key at the current depth of  (this) node.

Two possibilities:
a.) The accumulator does not contain a key that represents the depth of this node, so you have to create a new list of binary tree nodes and add it to the accumulator.
b.) The accumulator already has a key that represents the depth of this node, so you have to retrieve the list of binary tree nodes already there, and add this particular node to that list.

Also, if the left and right nodes are not null, then you want to recursively call this method at (depth+1) since they are lower on the tree than the current node.